# How to reset to all terminal settings/ or to delete all termianl apps in mac without loosing data and a time machine backup?

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-catalina, macos-mojave, macos-big-sur

I want to reset my mac but i don't have an external drive for making a backup.
I want all my personal files, and downloaded applications be there.
Just the environment settings, paths which is causing trouble for me in terminal is to be reset.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new user account in System Preferences > Users & Groups. Migrate your data over to the new account and delete the old one.

You can also try to address this by unhiding the files in your user folder in Finder with cmd-shift-. and directly editing the dotfiles that are causing you trouble with a regular text editor.

Comment: It won't help if something is installed as root, and that something is the root cause of the problem.